# Entity Framework Updating Included Records in Variable When Separate Query Is Executed

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

We want to pull an employee with their associated time sheet.  We also want to pull a weeks worth of a time sheet for other purposes.  What is happening here is after we save the records into the employee variable we are seeing there is one one record in the employeetimes include, but when the second linq query executes the employeeTimes variable gets filled with 10 records.  What is strange is the employeeTimes under the employee variable is also getting updated with 10 records.  What is going on here?

```cs
var employee = await _repo.GetEmployees()
            .Include(e => e.EmployeeTimes
                .Where(et => et.WorkDate == _currentBranchDate))
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e =>
                e.EmployeeNumber == employeeNumber,
                cancellationToken);


var employeeTimes = await _repo.GetEmployeeTimes()
    .OrderBy(x => x.WorkDate).ThenBy(x => x.StartTime)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x =>
        x.EmployeeNumber == employeeNumber &&
        x.WorkDate >= 20230809 &&
        x.WorkDate <= 20230815, cancellationToken);
```

Comment: *"What is going on here?"* It's called [tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking). Also see [Eager loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#eager-loading) and pay attention to the first **Tip** inside saying *"Entity Framework Core will automatically fix-up navigation properties to any other entities that were previously loaded into the context instance. So even if you don't explicitly include the data for a navigation property, the property may still be populated if some or all of the related entities were previously loaded."*

Comment: Also the **Caution** section of [Filtered include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include): *"In case of tracking queries, results of Filtered Include may be unexpected due to navigation fixup. All relevant entities that have been queried for previously and have been stored in the Change Tracker will be present in the results of Filtered Include query, even if they don't meet the requirements of the filter. Consider using NoTracking queries or re-create the DbContext when using Filtered Include in those situations."*

Comment: I added notracking and that worked!  If you want to put that as an answer I'll select it has the best answer.